# Constraint for specific bits

Tags: system-verilog, verification

I am trying to randomly constrain a 32-bit address.
Is there a way for me to constraint specific bits of the address?

```
rand bit [31:0] addr;

// last two bits should always be zero

req.randomize() with { addr[1:0] == 2'b00; };
```

Comment: that code should work. you can also use below `req.randomize(); loc_addr = {req.addr[31:2],2'b00}` it is rough way but will always work.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are ways to constrain specific bits of the address.

One way is to use `randomize with` as you have done.

Another way is to create a `constraint` block inside your `class`.  For example:

```
class foo;
    rand bit [31:0] addr;
    constraint c1 { addr[1:0] == 2'b00; }
endclass

module tb;

foo req = new();

initial begin
    repeat (5) begin
        req.randomize();
        $display(req.addr, "  ", req.addr[1:0]);
    end
end

endmodule
```

Output:

```
3053944240  0
2417184000  0
 629780252  0
 469272576  0
1715295476  0
```